# Is there a better way to do `git subtree pull` while using git-lfs?

Tags: git, git-subtree, git-lfs

I have two repositories: `parent` and `child`.  They both use git-lfs.  I am trying to import `child` as a subtree into `parent`.

When in the `parent` directory, I try adding it and I get the following:

```
> git subtree add --prefix child [child_url]
git fetch [child_url] master
From [child_url]
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Downloading [child_binary_file_path] (12.55 KB)
Error downloading object: [child_binary_file_path] ([sha])

Errors logged to .git\lfs\objects\logs\20170613T115607.1992713.log
Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.
error: external filter git-lfs smudge -- %f failed 2
error: external filter git-lfs smudge -- %f failed
fatal: [child_binary_file_path]: smudge filter lfs failed
```

In the log file, I see

```
Error downloading object: [child_binary_file_path] ([sha]): Smudge error: Error downloading [child_binary_file_path] ([sha]): [[sha]] Object does not exist on the server: [404] Object does not exist on the server

%+v
Smudge error: Error downloading [child_binary_file_path] ([sha]): [[sha]] Object does not exist on the server: [404] Object does not exist on the server
```

Which I guess makes sense, since the binary files for `child` *wouldn't* be on the server for `parent`.

So, I tried adding the `child` lfs files to `parent` like this, from the `parent` directory:

```
git remote add child [child_url]
git fetch child
git lfs fetch 
git lfs fetch child --all
git lfs push origin --all
```

Everything works fine until the last command.  The `git lfs push` doesn't push anything:

```
> git lfs push origin --all
Git LFS: (0 of 0 files, 1 skipped) 0 B / 0 B, 210 B skipped
```

It appears that it's only pushing to `parent` files that exist on `parent` branches.

The only way I could figure out how to add these lfs files to `parent` was to add the `child` branch to the `parent`.

```
git checkout -b temp_branch child/master
git push origin
```

This then lets me successfully call `git subtree add --prefix child [child_url] master`.

But, since I don't want `temp_branch` on `parent`, I must immediately delete it.

```
git branch -D temp_branch
git push origin --delete temp_branch
```

This works, but it feels *really* kludgey.

Is there a better way to call `git subtree add` when the subtree repository is using git-lfs?

Comment: I know it's been 6 years, but I am trying to do something similar and wondering if you found a solution?